A problem occurred configuring project ':[dependency name]', Name space not specified
Error image
Error Log
<
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':image_gallery_saver'.


Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.api.variant.impl.LibraryVariantBuilderImpl.
Namespace not specified. Specify a namespace in the module's build file. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/set-namespace for information about setting the namespace.

 If you've specified the package attribute in the source AndroidManifest.xml, you can use the AGP Upgrade Assistant to migrate to the namespace value in the build file. Refer to https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/agp-upgrade-assistant for general information about using the AGP Upgrade Assistant.


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 7s


I am trying to build a project where i am continuously getting name space error, as the log said, i have moved the namespace from AndroidManifest.xml file Android manifest file,
Additionaly when i remove a package the same error occure for the other package and so on,
i have also tried the different distributionUrl(Gradle version),when I set it to gradle-7.6.3-all.zip it gives error that minimum supported version is gradle-8.4-all.zip
the current state of the distribution url that is
#Tue Jun 04 19:54:51 PKT 2024
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.4-all.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists


now i am getting the namespace error even though the i have specied the namespace
android {
    compileSdkVersion 34
    namespace 'com.domainpart.domainpart'
    ...
}

I have implemented the suggestion specified in the error log url, I have also tried
[agp-upgrade-assistant]( https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/agp-upgrade-assistant) 

But no gain
Note that the dependencies versions are up-to date

Same issue, did you found solution?
